# Using VSTS to build/run Selenium tests defined in shared solution

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, continuous-delivery, user-acceptance-testing

I'm responsible for user acceptance testing for a .NET project being developed by a third party organisation. They have created a solution in VSTS and we're collaborating using the Agile process to communicate requirements and acceptance criteria via User Stories. The third party doing the development is responsible for completing their own testing prior to handing over for UAT.

To facilitate continuous delivery we have a UAT server and use Web Deploy to install new releases of the application using VSTS. I need to write Selenium tests to automate the UAT process. I'm wondering where I should put that project. I can add it to the existing solution but I don't want to get in the way of the developers. I see that VSTS has an option to build sources from a remote repository. So would this be a better option? Is there any guidance about a good approach for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If the work you are doing is separate from the developers, you can put the project in your own remote repo, and get sources from the remote repo in your build definition.
- If the working you are doing is associate with work the developers are doing, you should put the project in the same repo with the developers but use different branch from them so that you can merge/rebase easily.

  Assume the developers work on `master` branch in a git repo which is hosted on VSTS, you can create a branch `develop` from `master` branch, and define your CI build with `develop` branch to test UAT process automatically. So you can work for the same project separately. And if it’s needed, you can merge your work together.

Comment: Thanks yes I think a remote repo is the right option. I will be writing C# Selenium tests but need to keep them separate from the developers creating the functionality.